# AngularJS - Server 500 error not going through interceptor

Tags: angularjs, interceptor

I've got this interceptor setup to read XML I receive on all my requests:
https://gist.github.com/SantechDev/539a70208d23d8918ce0

Now when the server returns a 500 error, it doesn't seem like the response goes through the interceptor. I tried logging response but nothing comes up

Would anyone know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how yours has to work but the ones I wrote look totally different..

```
var interceptor = ['$rootScope', '$q', "Base64", function (scope, $q, Base64) {
    function success(response) {
        return response;
    }
    function error(response) {
        var status = response.status;
        if (status == 401) {
           window.location = "/account/login?redirectUrl=" + Base64.encode(document.URL);
            return;
        }
        // otherwise
        return $q.reject(response);
    }
    return function (promise) {
        return promise.then(success, error);
    }
}];
$httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push(interceptor);
```

you can check out the [full code here](https://github.com/stefchri/Radar/blob/master/Radar/RadarAPI/Radar/app/js/app.js).

Comment: sorry for late reply. I was actually forgetting to set the transformError. So your response is right